# Assign foreign key when submitting Django Form

Tags: django

I need to assign a non-nullable foreign key field to an object without neither showing this field in the template nor listing it as a form field.

Lets say I have a some model:

```
class SampleRecord(models.Model):
    foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(OtherModel, blank=False)
    some_field = models.CharField(...)
```

URL pattern I'm calling has a parameter which determines to which `OtherModel` object I'll be assigning new `SampleRecord` thus I have no need to add `foreign_key` field to Form because every time responsible url pattern is called:

```
.../new-record/123
```

I know that I need to create a new instance of `SampleRecord` assigned to `OtherModel` object with pk `123`. `SampleRecord` object may not exist without being assigned to `OtherModel` thus `foreign_key` field can not be `null`! Which means it has to be there when submitting the form. In this case I want to use a Form to create new `SampleRecord` and I don't want to determine foreign_key as field in this form because it'll require me setting a value for it:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SampleRecord
        fields = ['some_field']
```

I understand that I need to override `save` method inside my form, but I don't understand how to pass `OtherModel` object to a from a view and then assign it to new object after/during form validation.

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Django as well but when I do this, it is done in the View not the Form. I use this method in my View:

```
 def post(self, request):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        sub = form.save(commit=False)
        sub.sample_record_fk = SampleRecord.objects.get(pk=your_definition)
        sub.save()

        return redirect('Some URL')
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but it does not entirely apply to my question. I've updated the question a bit to make things clearer.